# message does not start with magic byte

Tags: go, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, sarama

I am trying to produce avro encoded data into kafka topic using **/linkedin/goavro** package in Go. The goal is to be able to consume the topic using different clients.

First I register the schema as following:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" --data '{"schema": "{\"name\":\"test_topic2\",\"type\":\"record\", \"fields\":[{\"name\":\"user\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"password\",\"size\":10,\"type\":\"string\"}]}"}' http://localhost:8081/subjects/test_topic2-value/versions
```

Then I create avro data, produce and consume it with Go.

```golang
package main

import (

    "github.com/Shopify/sarama"
    "github.com/linkedin/goavro"
    "fmt"

)
const (
    brokers = "localhost:9092"
    topic     = "test_topic2"
)

const loginEventAvroSchema = `{"name":"test_topic2","type":"record", "fields":[{"name":"user","type":"string"},{"name":"password","size":10,"type":"string"}]}`

func main() {

// Create Message

codec, err := goavro.NewCodec(loginEventAvroSchema)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

m := map[string]interface{}{
    "user": "pikachu", "password": 231231,
}

single, err := codec.SingleFromNative(nil, m)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}


// Producer
    config := sarama.NewConfig()
    config.Consumer.Return.Errors = true
    config.Producer.Return.Successes = true

    config.Version = sarama.V2_4_0_0
    //get broker
    cluster, err := sarama.NewSyncProducer(brokers, config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer func() {
        if err := cluster.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    msg := &sarama.ProducerMessage{
        Topic: topic,
        Value: sarama.StringEncoder(single),
    }

    cluster.SendMessage(msg)

// Consumer 

    clusterConsumer, err := sarama.NewConsumer(brokers, config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer func() {
        if err := clusterConsumer.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    msgK, _ := clusterConsumer.ConsumePartition(topic, 0, sarama.OffsetOldest)

    for {

        q := <-msgK.Messages()

        native, _, err := codec.NativeFromSingle([]byte(q.Value))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(native)

}
```

This code works fine and I can successfully produce and consume messages into the kafka topic.

Now I try to consume the topics from python avro-consumer:

```py
from confluent_kafka import KafkaError
from confluent_kafka.avro import AvroConsumer
from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer import SerializerError


c = AvroConsumer({
    'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost',
    'group.id': 'groupid',
    'schema.registry.url': 'http://localhost:8081',
    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'})


c.subscribe(['test_topic2'])

while True:
    try:
        msg = c.poll(10)

    except SerializerError as e:
        print("Message deserialization failed for {}: {}".format(msg, e))
        break

    if msg is None:
        continue

    if msg.error():
        print("AvroConsumer error: {}".format(msg.error()))
        continue

    print(msg.value(), msg.key())

c.close()
```

But I get the following error:

```
confluent_kafka.avro.serializer.SerializerError: Message deserialization failed for message at test_topic2 [0] offset 1: message does not start with magic byte
```

I think that I have missed something on the Go producer part, I would much appreciate it if someone can share his/her experience on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Is your key of type `avro` or `string`?

Comment: @Gio there is no key

Answer (score 1):

`goavro` doesn't use the Schema Registry.

Plus, you're using the `StringEncoder`, which I assume outputs only a string slice and not Avro bytes

> StringEncoder implements the Encoder interface **for Go strings** so that they can be used as the Key or Value in a ProducerMessage.

FWIW, I would suggest testing a consumer with kafka-avro-console-consumer, if you have it