# How to change unmarshaler in watermill (lib for Kafka) to avro

Tags: java, go, apache-kafka, avro

I'm trying to debug why it is no possible to de-serialize data we receive through Kafka and serialized with avro based on some specifics schema.

It looks like this.
There is a producer written in java which serializes data according some avro schema, sends that data to Kafka topic and on the consumer side there is a program written in Golang.

But each time I try to de-serialize that data I get error message saying that is was not possible to de serialize because length of the string is less than zero. (dependencies field)

Schema looks like this:

```
{
    "namespace": "data.avro",
    "doc":"Docstring.",
    "name": "Avrodata",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "id",       "type": "int"},
        {"name": "theName",      "type": "string"},
        {"name": "dependencies",  "type": {"type": "array", "items": "string"}}
    ]
}
```

My most recent suspicion is that maybe I need to change this Unmarshaler to avro but I have no idea how to do that.
I use this avro library https://github.com/hamba/avro and https://watermill.io/pubsubs/kafka/ for Kafka.

```
Unmarshaler:           kafka.DefaultMarshaler{},
```

I've tried to set Unmarshaler to something like avro.API{} but I got compiler error.

Based on this https://watermill.io/pubsubs/kafka/

```
kafka.SubscriberConfig{
            Brokers:               []string{"localhost:9092"},
            Unmarshaler:           kafka.DefaultMarshaler{},
            OverwriteSaramaConfig: saramaSubscriberConfig,
            ConsumerGroup:         "test_consumer_group",
        },
```

If I send data with golang and receive that data with golang everything works perfect.

Comment: Sounds like you need to write your own Struct that implements the Marshaller functions. What specific problems are you having with that?

Comment: I have no problem whatsoever I just simply do not understand what that functions (Marshal and Unmarshal) should do, because my guess is that they do not expect from me to implement whole algorithm. Right?

Comment: A long as they accept the correct parameters and return the type defined in the interface, doesn't really matter what else the functions do. You can see in the source code you've linked, how the default one extracts the key/value and headers. If you're running into a specific problem implementing Avro functionality, maybe it would be better to open a github issue

Comment: @OneCricketeer
Thank you for the hint.
Btw. Could this be the problem?, golang library does not support schema registry and java does.
https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/69
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60599237/message-does-not-start-with-magic-byte
so should I try and ignore first 4 bytes of payload send by java producer to Kafka topic when unmarshaling the data?

Comment: That depends if your Java producers do use the schema registry, but if they do, why not extract those bytes then lookup the schema?

Comment: @OneCricketeer https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format
I was right, after sending payload[5:] to unmarshal function everything works perfect. :)

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format

> In most cases, you can use the serializers and formatter directly and not worry about the details of how messages are mapped to bytes. However, if you’re working with a language that Confluent has not developed serializers for, or simply want a deeper understanding of how the Confluent Platform works, here is more detail on how data is mapped to low-level bytes.

Bytes from 5th to the end of payload contains actual serialized data.

> Serialized data for the specified schema format (for example, binary encoding for Avro or Protocol Buffers). The only exception is raw bytes, which will be written directly without any special encoding.
> So

```
avro.Unmarshal(schema, data[5:], out);
```

will unmarshal that data which was serialized with language that Confluent has developed serializers for. :)

Cheers.

Comment: But if you didn't skip the ID, then you don't need to carry around your schema as part of the code for deserialization. You can look it up from the registry with an HTTP client

Comment: OK. This is something I don't quite understand, why do we need both schema and registry schema? What is the correlation between the two?
Or is it something you just explained to me. I do not need "local" schema if I have this registry schema?

Comment: The registry is an API/"database" backed by a Kafka topic where the AVSC schemas are stored, per topic. You'd use the bytes`int(data[1:4])`, with `GET http://registry-address:8081/schemas/ids/:id`, then you can parse this response to get the schema for that topic. This would be the same address that your Java producer had used, for example

Comment: How you can store AVSC per Kafka topic? I ask because it's not done by some magic, this I know for sure. :) Kafka running on my laptop does not provide any schema on localhost:8081 or 8082 (I can not remember :)).

Comment: Kafka runs on 9092. The registry is 8081. Follow the tutorials and read the API docs to understand how things are stored. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema_registry_tutorial.html  You can also look at the Java source code for `KafkaAvroSerializer` on github